# What will be the corresponding query in Spark SQL to this Pandas operation?

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe, `df`,  with 5 columns

```
student_id
course_id
course_date
attendance_id
```

None of these columns are unique, but the combination of `student_id` and `attendance_id` will be unique. I want to create a new dataframe `new_df` which is unique for `student_id` by selecting the earliest course_date. In Pandas, I do this by:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['student_id']).apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(1,'course_date')).reset_index(drop=1)
```

If df had 1600 rows with 1000 distinct student_id, then new_df will have 1000 rows with 1000 distinct student_id.

How can I do this in Spark SQL or even normal SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT student_id, min(course_date)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY student_id
```